# Odata in .Net 6 returns byte[] properties with null Value if $select is used

Tags: .net, odata, .net-6.0

I'm currently using .Net 6 to Provide a Odata endpoint.
When I do a Get call like this
https://localhost:7139/Odata/Documents
Result is good

[image]

But when I use `$select` to have only specified properties the `byte[]` is empty
https://localhost:7139/odata/Documents?$select=ID,FileName,Data

[image]

Do I need to configure my application to include byte[] in case of `$select`? Because it still works with `$filter` and other operations. It only does that with `$select`

Here is how I configure my odata service in *Program.cs*:

```
static void InitialzeOdata(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    modelBuilder.EntitySet<Document>("Documents");

    builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(
        options => options.EnableQueryFeatures().AddRouteComponents(
            "odata",
            modelBuilder.GetEdmModel())
        );
}
```

And this is my Get Method in `DocumentController`:
[image]

```
[EnableQuery]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Document>> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Document> options)
{
    IQueryable results = applicationDbContext.Documents.AsQueryable();
    if (options.Filter != null)
    {
        results = options.Filter.ApplyTo(applicationDbContext.Documents.AsQueryable(), new ODataQuerySettings());
    }
    if (CheckIfDataSelected(options))
    {
        foreach (Document item in results)
        {
            item.Data = fileService.LoadFile(item.ID.ToString());
        }
    }
    return Ok(results as IQueryable<Document>);
}
```

Comment: Could you share a code of the method CheckIfDataSelected(...)?

Comment: What happens if you remove the CheckIfDataSelected and set *Data* to a static dummy value?